# Get the Current Blog URL of User in Multi Site?

Tags: multisite

I have a WordPress Multi Site installation and several blogs. On the frontpage (domain.com) I have a login form and when the user is logged in, it shows two links at the moment (Admin Panel and Log out). But I also want to include a link that goes to the current blog site of the user, eg: blog.domain.com.

```
<li class="showblog"><a href="<?php <some code> ?>">Show blog</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

try use this function,,

```
function get_primary_blog_url($id=null) {
  // is there a user to check?
  global $current_user;
  $user_id = (null != $id ) ? $id : $current_user->ID;

  if ( isset( $user_id ) ) {
    // Get the blogs of this user
    $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );

    // Get the URL of the blog
    foreach ( $user_blogs AS $user_blog ) {
      if ( $user_blog->userblog_id != BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE ) { 
        return $user_blog->siteurl;
      }
    }
    // If user has no blog, return to the homepage.
  } else {
    return home_url();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "`current blog`" in WPMU terms means the blog that is actually shown in the moment. In other words the current blog context of the page that is viewed in that moment or the content of `global $blog_id`. As in a normal wp install you would use [site_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) to retreive the link of that blog. *(Just pointing this out so you don't get confused by that wording later.)*

I think what you are searching for is the url to the blog which belongs to that user. There is no direct function for this. The best way to get this information is to use [get_blogs_of_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blogs_of_user) to get a list of blogs a user is attached to. If your setup is configured in a way that it's only possible for a user to have one blog, you can just use the first element from that array.

Simple example:

```
<?php
    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( get_current_user_id() );
    $link = get_site_url($blogs[0]->userblog_id);
?>
<li class="showblog"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Show blog</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes, i searching for a way to get the URL to the blog which belongs to the user. I've tried your example and it gives me this link: domain.com/Array

Comment: @Cyb3 I updated the code.

Comment: Sorry, but the user only got to frontpage:, domain.com.

Comment: Then the user has no blogs? Did you try to check the return value of the get_blogs_of_user() using var_dump()?

Comment: I tried it and it output: string(16) "http://domain.com" - I even created a new blog and tried with that user and the same result occurred.

Comment: The interesting piece is the content of the `$blogs` variable. You should look at that.